# Tag synonym [spaces] to [space]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[spaces](/questions/tagged/spaces) should be made synonym to [space](/questions/tagged/space). As far as I know, I don't think there is anything that either of them specifically refers to. If it does, then disambiguation is necessary.

Comment: Perhaps they both should be made synonyms of `whitespace`?

Comment: Not sure, but indeed many questions are related to whitespace. The rests are a bunch of questions that are about different types of "space" (disk space, space in user interface, etc.).

Comment: What if there are questions about outer space?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Send it to black hole, then.

Comment: yes, this is already mentioned in the dup.