# Should the Space tag be banished?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just rejected an edit that was trying to add the [space](/questions/tagged/space) tag to a question, on the bases of it being a meaningless tag.

Why do we have this tag?

Comment: What are the stats? What's using it?

Comment: Seems to be applied similarly to [whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace) - might be a good synonym.

Comment: @Tim, not that simple, is is also used on some database quesions about disk space.   (I only looked at few quesions that use it.)

Comment: And there might some about _space_ (the outer space)!

Comment: @devnull then they should use the [tag:blackspace] tag.

Comment: Oh ick. While it's not quite a meta tag, it's _definitely_ an ambiguous one. Ho hum, time to take a much deeper look.

Comment: @TimPost: I suspect most of non-whitespace uses are simply the result of people typing "disk space" into the tag box, and can thus be found with [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disk+space). There also seems to be a few ["heap space"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap+space) questions, but I think [that's pretty much it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space+-disk+-heap).

Comment: Anyway, it looks like a completely useless tag to me (and I'm not sure [tag:whitespace] is much better, either). Let's space it.

Comment: "Comma" is anther related meaningless tag

Comment: Given the asking and answering patterns, it is not a topic anyone specializes in (most of the high scoring users have just a single question or answer with the tag `space`).  See the [What value does the `save` tag provide on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213446/what-value-does-the-save-tag-provide-on-stack-overflow) question for where that heuristic comes from.

Answer (score 3):

> ## [space](/questions/tagged/space)
>
> Space characters in text systems indicate separation between words or glyphs. While most      Western scripts use only one space character, Unicode defines multiple different kinds of whitespace characters for use in specialized typography functions and in Asian languages.

If you read a question like [Replace %20 with space character while saving file iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485569/replace-20-with-space-character-while-saving-file-ios), it actually seems to match the tag wiki, though it seems it would serve as a good synonym for [whitespace](/questions/tagged/whitespace) (see "*any combination of spaces*" in the tag wiki), only [space](/questions/tagged/space) also refers to space between components, so it could be used in a question asking about, for example, margin in CSS (["Unexpected CSS token: {" in Safari and unexplained gap between divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322668/unexpected-css-token-in-safari-and-unexplained-gap-between-divs)).  In any case, [spaces](/questions/tagged/spaces) could be a tag synonym of [space](/questions/tagged/space) or [whitespace](/questions/tagged/whitespace), also, so we seem to have lots of different types of [space](/questions/tagged/space) tags that could all be synonyms to a simple tag that has a tag description reading

> Unicode character U+0020, space between components, and any combination of spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the list of questions on the first page, they are discussing all sorts of different types of [space](/questions/tagged/space), and only a few are concerned with U+0020 and its near relatives.  That alone means that the tag is of dubious quality; it does not clearly help you refine your search to relevant questions because all sorts of questions are classified as relevant.

I note that there is a [synonym suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138839/tag-synonym-spaces-to-space) that [spaces](/questions/tagged/spaces) (432 questions) should be made into a synonym of [space](/questions/tagged/space) (888 questions). The question has been closed as a duplicate, but the duplicate hasn't been acted on either (at least w.r.t these two tags — I've now proposed that `spaces` should be a recognized synonym of `space`).  The duplicate is a generic request to merge singular/plural tags.

On the whole, I think many — possibly most — of the questions do not warrant the [space](/questions/tagged/space) tag, and it should largely be burninated.  I'm willing to compromise in that there are some questions where the official description of the tag matches the content of the question, but I'm not sure how useful the tag would be.